# Play two audio sources during a live video stream

Tags: azure-media-services

I'm working with the Azure Media Player( https://ampdemo.azureedge.net/ ).  I need a second audio source (which will be music) to be overlaid on top of the video with presenter talking.  I see there's the ability to select multiple audio streams if the video is stored on Azure. (English/spanish/etc...)  However, in my case it will be video and presenter(talking) on the video live stream and I'd like to be able to select a music stream of the viewers choice during the live stream which will be stored music in Azure.

Is this possible?

Then take it to the next step, does the player provide the capability of setting the volume on each stream?  If not, is the player extendable?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Media Player(AMP) doesn't allow playing multiple audio streams at the same time. You could achieve your desired behavior by including a hidden HTML5 video player and use that to play your additional audio. You'll probably want to use javascript to "synchronize" the hidden video player with Azure Media Player, i.e. When AMP plays, you play the hidden video player. When AMP pauses, you pause the hidden video player.

Comment: Hmm.  How is the english / spanish encoded into this? https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/samples/dynamic_selectAudioStream.html  Is it encoded into the video itself or is it a separate stream?  Or is this only in stored content and not live streams?